# Labeling Simultaneous Equations?

Tags: support, mathjax, equation

I'm aware that you can label a single line with \tag:

$$2x+3y=5\tag{1}$$

But can you do this with simultaneous equations? For example, each of the following in:

$$\begin{cases} 2x+3y=5 \\ x-y=19 \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option for you: You can use the "align" environment.  The symbol, in the first case, that I'll align is `=`.  To do that, for every occurrence of $=$, precede it with `&` separate lines with `\\` or `\\ \\` as desired, but at the end of each line to be, prior to `\\`, you can use `\tag{*}` to label each and every line.

For example, given the following code:

`\begin{align} 
2x+3y &= 5 \tag{1} \\ 
x-y &=19\tag{2} 
\end{align}`

We get $$\begin{align} 2x+3y &= 5 \tag{1} \\ x-y&=19\tag{2} \end{align} $$

---

In order to left align the equations, we move the `&` to the beginning of each equation, as follows:

`\begin{align} 
& 2x+3y = 5 \tag{1} \\ 
& x-y =19\tag{2} 
\end{align}`

\begin{align} 
& 2x+3y = 5 \tag{1} \\ 
& x-y =19\tag{2} 
\end{align}

---

There are so many neat things you can do with formatting.  I've learned many of those neat things on this site.  Look around at other posts; e.g., search systems of equations, and look at the answers; when you see something you'd like to replicate, hover over it, right-click, click "Show Math As: and then click "Tex Commands"

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and answering.  I would still like to have the left bracket symbolic of simultaneous equations however... is there a way to do that?

Comment: Try this: `\begin{cases} 2x+3y=5 & (1) \\ x-y=19 & (2)\end{cases}`  to get \begin{cases} 2x+3y=5 & (1) \\ x-y=19 & (2)\end{cases}

Comment: That's an improvisation.  You can use & to describe or label the the equation.

Comment: Yep that's the only solution I've come up with myself.  It gets a little hazy if the two equations don't have exactly the same line length, but it is what it is....

Comment: Note, though, that using `& (1)` and `&(2)`  the labels align.  You can get more space by ending each equation with `& & (1)`, etc.

Comment: Indeed that seems to be the best solution.  Nothing so nice as using the tag though.

Comment: :O Never knew you could use multiple ampersands like that.

Answer (score -3):

$$
\begin{align}
A + B & = C \\
D + E & = F \\
G + H & = I \\
J + K & = L
\end{align} \tag 1
$$

Here is the code for what appears above.

```
$$
\begin{align}
A + B & = C \\
D + E & = F \\
G + H & = I \\
J + K & = L
\end{align} \tag 1
$$
```

If you put \tag 1 before rather than after \begin{align} then the number is on the right after the first line.

$$\begin{cases} 2x+3y=5 \\ x-y=19 \end{cases} \tag 1 $$

Comment: I think the asker is looking for a way to number **each equation in the set of simultaneous equations**. So given your example, we have both equations identified as (1) ?

Comment: @amWhy : The poster does use the word "each" and I was aware that that was probably the immediate concern. But $(1)$ several people had already dealt with that and $(2)$ that's not substantially different from what is done with just one line: you merely put a tag on each line separately, and $(3)$ it is sometimes worth knowing about what I point out in my posting.

Comment: I agree that what you say  is worth knowing.  Please understand, I did not down-vote your answer.